# Removing all white-spaces except for tabs and linebreaks

Tags: removing-whitespace

Is there a way to remove all whitespace characters except for tabs and linebreaks?
If I were to use .replaceAll("\s+", "") or .replaceAll(" ", "") I would also delete every tab or linebreak.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: usually you can specify a list a (special) characters to replace with [], so you can put each white space you're thinking about between these [ \t\n\r] and remove them. Replacing " " should also usually NOT remove anything else than spaces...

Answer (score 0):

for python language, you can use this function:

```
def replaceWhiteSpace(text):
    res = []
    for i in text:
        res = text.str.split()
        for j in res:
            text2 = ' '.join(j)
    return text2

testDataset = replaceWhiteSpace(text)
```

put your a column in your dataframe in **text**, and the result will be stored in **testDataset**